# Ruby - What is the difference between intern and to_sym

Tags: ruby, methods, symbols

I came across the Ruby String Documentation and tested out the methods. Two methods I found to be similar are the to_sym and intern methods.

```
"cat".intern
=> :cat

"cat".to_sym
=> :cat
```

I searched Stack Overflow and surprisingly this hasn't been asked. I myself can find no difference between the two so I thought I would ask this.

If they do the same thing, is one method faster than the other? If so, it would make sense to use that method.

Comment: `to_sym` is merely an alias for `intern`, the latter having been created in the midst of time.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

They seem to be aliases for the same thing. From the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-intern) you can see that the sample code of `intern` uses `to_sym`:

> ## intern → symbol
>
> Returns the Symbol corresponding to str, creating the symbol if it did
>   not previously exist. See `Symbol#id2name`.
>
> ```
> "Koala".intern         #=> :Koala
> s = 'cat'.to_sym       #=> :cat
> s == :cat              #=> true
> s = '@cat'.to_sym      #=> :@cat
> s == :@cat             #=> true
> ```
>
> This can also be used to create symbols that cannot be represented
>   using the :xxx notation.
>
> ```
> 'cat and dog'.to_sym   #=> :"cat and dog"
> ```

Comment: If you expand their source views, they both list the definition of `rb_str_intern()`.

Comment: As expected, looks like there's no difference. In that case is one method faster in terms of performance? If so then that would be the correct method to use

Comment: @user3713082 They aren't competing definitions. They're just aliases. So, there shouldn't be any difference in performance.

Comment: Here it's very sure that it is the same:  https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/512a675cf116c52d0d00674b

Comment: That is bloody awful example code. Why would they give you examples showing to_sym instead of using actual alias without pointing out that it's an alias. *sigh* I've seen this a lot in the docs where there actual method isn't used in the examples and I don't understand why it keeps happening.

Comment: I think it comes from Ruby's roots in Smalltalk. Smalltalk had a method called `intern`. `to_sym` is more Ruby-like.

Answer (score 1):

[Rubocop](https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) uses this comparison as an example in one of its linter cops: [Style/StringMethods](https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cops_style/#stylestringmethods) by the default setting for this cop `to_sym` is preferred over `intern`, without any reference to a style guide or further documentation.  My personal observation is that the choice is made due to readability alone; given that performance is not an issue as stated in the other answers.